# Showing that $\lim_{Q\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\sum_{p<Q}1\right|=0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

As the title of the question susggests, I would like to show that

The "trivial bound is that"

\begin{align*}
\lim_{Q\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|&\leq \lim_{Q\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left(\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p+\pi(Q)\right)\\
&=2
\end{align*}

where the equality is obtained by noting that $\frac{1}{p}$ numbers are multiplies of $p$, so the expected value of $\sum_{\substack{p<q \\ p|n}}p$ is exactly $\sum_{p<Q}1=\pi(Q)$. Thus, we are looking only for a "$o(\cdot)$" improvement. The first thought of mine would be to note that since $\sum_{\substack{p<q \\p|n}}p$ is an additive function and so by the Turan-Kubilius inequality

$$\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|^2\leq 4N\sum_{p<Q}p$$

The issue is, this inequality is worse than the trivial one since apply Cauchy-Shwartz we get that this inequality yields

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|&\leq \frac{1}{\pi(Q)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|^2}\\
&\leq \frac{2}{\pi(Q)}\sqrt{\sum_{p<Q}p}\\
\end{align*}

where by the PNT this last term is on the order of $\sqrt{\frac{Q^2}{\log(Q)}}=\frac{Q}{\sqrt{\log(Q)}}$. This inequality would indicate to us that the sum would $\mathit{diverge}$, namely

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|=\Omega(\sqrt{\log(Q)})$$

I have proved that the sum can't go to zero too fast, and specifically that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|=\Omega(\log(Q)^{-\epsilon})$$

for any $\epsilon>0$. It does, however, feel natural that this sum should be at least $o(1)$.

Comment: I think the third equation should read: $\cdots \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}\pi(Q)} \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\cdots}$ which implies that the limit as $N$ tends to infinity is $0$.

Comment: @DavidTweedle Are you sure that you accounted for the extra factor of $N$ that appears in the square root when you apply Cauchy-Shwartz?

Comment: The inner limit, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac 1{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{p<Q,\,p|n} p-\pi(Q)\right|$ is exactly $\frac1{M\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<M}\left|\sum_{p<Q,\,p|n} p-\pi(Q)\right|$, where $M$ is the product of all primes less than $Q$ since the summand in absolute values is $M$-periodic in $n$.

Comment: If $n$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,\ldots,M\}$, then the events $p|n$ are mutually independent for all $p<Q$. This means you can rewrite the inner limit as $\frac 1{\pi(Q)}\mathbb E\left|\sum_{p<Q} X_p-\pi(Q)\right|$, where the $X_p$'s are independent random variables taking the value $p$ with probability $\frac 1p$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @MiloMoses Yes, I made a mistake. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the conjecture is **false**, if I did not miss some asymptotc issue The essence of what follows is that I show that the interior limit exceeds *any* function of $Q$ tending to $0$.

For any $t\geq 1$, denote by $p_t(Q)$ the density of those $n$ divisible by at least one $p$ with $t\pi(Q)<p<Q$. We have
\begin{align*}
  p_t(Q)&=1-\prod_{t\pi(Q)<p<Q}\left(1-\frac1p\right)
  \sim 1-\exp\left(\sum_{t\pi(Q)<p<Q}\frac1p\right)
  \sim 1-\frac{\log Q}{\log (t\pi(Q))}\\
  &\sim 1-\frac{\log Q}{\log Q+\log t-\log\log Q}
  =\frac{\log\log Q-\log t}{\log Q+\log t-\log\log Q}\\
  &\sim \frac{\log\log Q-\log t}{\log Q},
\end{align*}
where the estimates work in the regime $t\leq o(Q/\pi(Q))=o(\log Q)$. (More precisely, in any such regime this equivalence is *uniform* over $t\leq o(\log Q)$, as $q\to\infty$.)

Assume now that your conjecture is true, i.e., that
$$
  f(Q):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right| \to 0, \qquad Q\to\infty.
$$
Take $N$ to be a multiple of $Q!$. Notice that at least $p_t(Q)N$ of the summands are larger than $(t-1)\pi(Q)$. Put $q=\log Q$. Summing up over $t=2,3,\dots,qf(Q)=o(q)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
  \frac1{N\pi(Q)}\sum_{n<N}\left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|
  &\buildrel(*)\over\ge \sum_{t=2}^{qf(Q)} p_t(Q)
  \sim \sum_{t=2}^{qf(Q)} \frac{\log q-\log t}{q}
  =\frac1q\log\frac{q^{qf(Q)}}{(qf(Q))!}\\
  &\sim \frac1q\log\left(\frac{qe}{qf(Q)}\right)^{qf(Q)}
  \sim f(Q)(-\log f(Q)).
\end{align*}
Since $f(Q)=o(1)$, the limit of the above expression as $N\to\infty$ cannot equal $f(Q)$.

**Remark.** The inequality $(*)$ holds, because if a number $n$ is accounted for $x$ times in the right sum, then its large prime divisor $p$ is larger than $(x+1)\pi(Q)$, so that
$$
  \left|\sum_{\substack{p<Q\\p|n}}p-\pi(Q)\right|>x\pi(Q).
$$

Comment: Are you sure that there are no issues with counting numbers multiple times in the sum $\sum_{t=2}^{qf(Q)}p_t(Q)$? If it is the density of primes where at least on prime divides in that in those intervals, numbers which appear in the tightest interval will also appear in every other term.

Comment: It seems that I am; notice that there is no $\sim$ sign there. I've added a clarification in the Remark at the end. If you are unsure about some other steps --- feel free to ask, this is really sketchy; sorry for that.

Comment: Could you expand the last step in the first line of math where you claim that $1-\frac{\log(Q)}{\log(t\pi(Q))}$ is asymptotic to a much simpler expression (and at a uniform rate)

Comment: I've inserted a line into the equation. Is it really the place you got troubls, or perhaps you meany a different one?

Comment: Though it pains me to say it, I can't find any more questionable steps in your proof. Thank you very much for your help.